# creating unique id into object without UUID in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to test my understanding of React but hit a mental block. Would it be possible to create a unique key  / id within my `<FormInput>` component rather than creating the unique ID inside the `<MainUI>` component once the newly created item is passed up into `<MainUI>`? I find that weird and definitely feel like there is a way better method of doing this.

```
const MainUI = props => {

    const receiveNewItem = enteredNewItem => {
        const newItem = {
            ...enteredNewItem,
            id: Math.random().toString()
        }
        props.addNewItem(newItem)
        
    }

    console.log(props.data)
    return(
        <div>
            <FormInput receiveNewItem={receiveNewItem}/>
            {/* <MaxAmount data={props.data} /> */}
            <DisplayItems data={props.data} key={props.data.id} />
        </div>
    ) 
}

export default MainUI;
```

```
import { useState } from 'react'

import Card from './Card'

const FormInput = props => {

    const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState({
        name: '',
        amount: '',
        date: ''
    })

    const nameInputHandler = e => {
        setUserInput( prevObj => {
            return {...prevObj, name: e.target.value}
    
        })
    }

    const amountInputHandler = e => {
        setUserInput( prevObj => {
            return {...prevObj, amount: e.target.value}
    
        })
    }

    const dateInputHandler = e => {
        setUserInput( prevObj => {
            return {...prevObj, date: e.target.value}
    
        })
    }
    
    const submitHandler = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        props.receiveNewItem(userInput)
        setUserInput( prevObj => { return {...prevObj, name: ''}}) 
    }

    return (
        <Card>
            <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    placeholder="Name Input" 
                    value={userInput.name} 
                    onChange={nameInputHandler} />

                <input 
                    type="number" 
                    placeholder="Amount Input" 
                    value={userInput.amount} 
                    onChange={amountInputHandler} />
                
                <input 
                    type="date" 
                    placeholder="Date Input" 
                    value={userInput.date} 
                    onChange={dateInputHandler} />



                <button>Add Item</button>
            </form>
        </Card>   
    )
}

export default FormInput;
```

Comment: So the key prop should be directly passed in order to perform the desired behavior. In your case, it is nested under receiveNewItem. Please let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: Of course it's possible; just move the code that adds the `id` property into `submitHandler` and out of `receiveNewItem`...

Comment: Thank you both! Was able to figure it out from the tips given. I did a props.data.map then passed to <DisplayItems key={item.id} /> then just styled the props passed with a custom <Card> component.

The id update i moved to the <FormInput>'s submitHandler as suggested and worked